# Giving OriginAccessIdentity reference in CloudFormation or serverless.yml

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, serverless

I want to have a CloudFront distribution with access to a private S3 bucket. For that, I have to create an origin access identity. Manually, I can do that using the AWS console, but I wanted to create it via a CloudFormation script or with Serverless (using `serverless.yml`). While doing this, I am able to add a physical Id of the origin access identity to my CloudFront distribution (using one script).

Relevant documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-cloudfront.html

I tried this:

```
myDistribution:
  Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
  Properties:
    DistributionConfig:
      Origins:
      - DomainName:bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
        Id: myS3Origin
        S3OriginConfig: {
          OriginAccessIdentity:origin-access-identity/cloudfront/ !Ref cloudfrontoriginaccessidentity
        }
      Enabled: 'true'
      Comment: Some comment
      DefaultCacheBehavior:
        ForwardedValues:
          QueryString: 'false'
          Cookies:
            Forward: none
        AllowedMethods:
        - GET
        - HEAD
        - OPTIONS
        TargetOriginId: myS3Origin
        ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
      PriceClass: PriceClass_200
      ViewerCertificate:
        CloudFrontDefaultCertificate: 'true'
cloudfrontoriginaccessidentity:
  Type: AWS::CloudFront::CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity
  Properties:
    CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig:
      Comment: "some comment"
```

I have to create an origin access identity and a CloudFront distribution having this identity. Can we do both of these things in one CloudFormation script or with Serverless (using `serverless.yml`)?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Alex I am getting  "The specified origin access identity does not exist or is not valid. (Service: AmazonCloudFront;
Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidOriginAccessIdentity; Request ID: 79f6a033-3202-11e9-911d-0d536d188164)."    problem is    , we have to mention   Origin access identity as   "OriginAccessIdentity:origin-access-identity/cloudfront/ETRATTARR"  under s3 origin config.  But when we use "!Ref cloudfrontoriginaccessidentity" we will get only id ETRATTARR). I want to append that id to "OriginAccessIdentity:origin-access-identity/'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You definitely can create an origin access identity and the CloudFront distribution in the same `serverless.yml`.

I've modified your scenario and changed the `OriginAccessIdentity` to use `Fn::Join`.

```
myDistribution:
  Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
  Properties:
    DistributionConfig:
      Origins:
      - DomainName:bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
        Id: myS3Origin
        S3OriginConfig:
          OriginAccessIdentity:
            Fn::Join:
              - ''
              -
                - 'origin-access-identity/cloudfront/'
                - Ref: cloudfrontoriginaccessidentity
      Enabled: 'true'
      Comment: Some comment
      DefaultCacheBehavior:
        ForwardedValues:
          QueryString: 'false'
          Cookies:
            Forward: none
        AllowedMethods:
        - GET
        - HEAD
        - OPTIONS
        TargetOriginId: myS3Origin
        ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
      PriceClass: PriceClass_200
      ViewerCertificate:
        CloudFrontDefaultCertificate: 'true'

cloudfrontoriginaccessidentity:
  Type: AWS::CloudFront::CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity
  Properties:
    CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig:
      Comment: "some comment"
```

The serverless examples repo has a great example of this too: https://github.com/serverless/examples/blob/master/aws-node-single-page-app-via-cloudfront/serverless.yml

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create both in the same CloudFormation template. The `cloudfrontoriginaccessidentity` is a separate resource so needs to be moved out from underneath `myDistribution`.

```
myDistribution:
      Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
      Properties:
        DistributionConfig:
          Origins:
          - DomainName:bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
            Id: myS3Origin
            S3OriginConfig: {
              OriginAccessIdentity:origin-access-identity/cloudfront/ !Ref cloudfrontoriginaccessidentity
            }
          Enabled: 'true'
          Comment: Some comment
          DefaultCacheBehavior:
            ForwardedValues:
              QueryString: 'false'
              Cookies:
                Forward: none
            AllowedMethods:
            - GET
            - HEAD
            - OPTIONS
            TargetOriginId: myS3Origin
            ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
          PriceClass: PriceClass_200
          ViewerCertificate:
            CloudFrontDefaultCertificate: 'true'
cloudfrontoriginaccessidentity:
  Type: AWS::CloudFront::CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity
  Properties:
    CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig:
    Comment: "toyoguard-acces-identity"
```

Comment: I am getting "The specified origin access identity does not exist or is not valid. (Service: AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidOriginAccessIdentity; Request ID: 79f6a033-3202-11e9-911d-0d536d188164)." problem is , we have to mention Origin access identity as "OriginAccessIdentity:origin-access-identity/cloudfront/ETRATTARR" under s3 origin config. But when we use "!Ref cloudfrontoriginaccessidentity" we will get only id ETRATTARR). I want to append that id to "OriginAccessIdentity:origin-access-identity

Comment: This is not the answer, just a problem with how the original question was formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to add the s3 policy and bucket to your dependsOn list